# Primefaces SelectOneMenu passing Labels instead of Values

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:selectOneMenu>` on my page, it receives a map for its values:

```
                    <p:selectOneMenu style="width:160px;  float:right;"
                        value="#{aba.ln}" rendered="#{aba.selecaoAtiva}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{aba.itens}" />
                        <p:ajax update="@form" event="change" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

It is rendering the following HTML for the select:

```
<select name="j_idt72:j_idt73:j_idt77_input" id="j_idt72:j_idt73:j_idt77_input">
    <option selected="selected" value="71xxxxUG">LABEL ONE</option>
    <option value="71yyyyUG">LABEL TWO</option>
</select>
```

but the ajax is sending the LABELS to the backing bean.

---

After fiddling a while, i removed the `event="change"` from the `<p:ajax>`, and it started passing values again.

So, question is, why having `<p:ajax update="@form" event="change" />` sends labels to the backing bean, while `<p:ajax update="@form" />` sends the values?

Comment: possible related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022965/why-selectonemenu-send-itemlabel-to-the-converter

Comment: Do you have a `@FacesConverter(forClass)` for this class? If so, then it's broken.

Comment: Nope. no converter @BalusC (that I know of). the behavior of the ajax call is: with event="change" it passes the labels, without it passes values (as expected). both labels and values are Strings. When I get to work on monday, I will post the backing bean code.

Comment: I'd report it to PrimeFaces guys. The default event for `UIInput` components is by the way `valueChange`.