# JSF selectOneMenu entity conversion fails with CDI converter

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, cdi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why selectOneMenu Send ItemLabel to the converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022965/why-selectonemenu-send-itemlabel-to-the-converter)

I have a JSF page with two `p:selectOneMenu` on it which both represent pretty simple entities.

ListType entity:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "LISTTYPES" )
@NamedQueries
(
    {
        @NamedQuery( name  = "...",
                     query = "SELECT lty " +
                             "FROM ListType lty " +
                             "WHERE lty.name = :name "),
    }
)
public class ListType implements ClientDependent, Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column( name = "LISTTYPE_ID" )
    private Long               id;

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "LIST_NO" )
    private Long               nbr;

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "LIST_NAME" )
    private String             name;

    @Column( name = "LIST_DESC" )
    private String             description;

    ...
}
```

MonitoringReason entity:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "MONITORINGREASONS" )
@NamedQueries
(
    {
        @NamedQuery( name  = "...",
                     query = "SELECT mtr " +
                             "FROM MonitoringReason mtr " +
                             "WHERE mtr.code = :code"),
    }
)
public class MonitoringReason implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column( name = "MONITORINGREASON_ID" )
    private Long               id;

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "MONITORINGREASON_NO" )
    private String             code;

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "MONITORINGREASON_NAME" )
    private String             name;

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "MONITORINGREASON_DESC" )
    private String             description;

    ...
}
```

Simple entities. Note, I omitted the equals + hashCode methods, which both entities implement correctly.

Here's some example data:

List type data:

```
LISTTYPE_ID  LIST_NO  LIST_NAME           LIST_DESC
      1         3       'WL'        'Watch List'
      0         4       'RL'        'Restricted List'
      2         5       'Emb'       'Embargo'
      7         7       'NRL'       'Not Recommended List'
   5009        14       'GWL'       'Global Watch List'
   5010        15       'GRL'       'Global Restricted List'
   5011        16       'PIL'       'Permanent Insider List'
```

Monitoring reason data:

```
MONITORINGREASON_ID  MONITORINGREASON_NO  MONITORINGREASON_NAME  MONITORINGREASON_DESC
        3                   'Ah'           'Ad-Hoc'              'Ad-Hoc'
        6                   'Al'           'Autom. Liste'        'Automatische Liste'
        4                   'Be'           'Beobachtung'         'Beobachtung'
        7                   'CLC'          'Limit Changes'       'Limit Changes'
        1                   'Fus'          'Fusion'              'Fusion'
        5                   'Li'           'Liste'               'Liste'
        2                   'Res'          'Research'            'Research Unternehmen'
```

The named queries on the entities above are for finding the entities by the converters:

ListTypeConverter.java:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ListTypeConverter implements Converter
{
    @Inject
    @SeamLogger
    private Logger log;

    @Inject
    private SessionHelper sessionHelper;

    @Inject
    private ListTypeService listTypeService;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject( FacesContext ctx, UIComponent comp, String identifier )
    {
        this.log.info( getClass().getSimpleName() + ".getAsObject: " + identifier );

        if ( identifier == null )
        {
            return null;
        }

        ListType listType = this.listTypeService.findByClientIdAndName( this.sessionHelper.getLoginUser().getClientId(), identifier );

        this.log.info( "Returning " + listType.getName() +  "!" );

        return listType;
    }

    ...
}
```

MonitoringReasonConverter.java:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MonitoringReasonConverter implements Converter
{
    @Inject
    @SeamLogger
    private Logger log;

    @Inject
    private SessionHelper sessionHelper;

    @Inject
    private MonitoringReasonService monitoringReasonService;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject( FacesContext ctx, UIComponent comp, String identifier )
    {
        this.log.info( getClass().getSimpleName() + ".getAsObject: " + identifier );

        if ( identifier == null )
        {
            return null;
        }

        MonitoringReason monitoringReason = this.monitoringReasonService.findByClientIdAndCode( this.sessionHelper.getLoginUser().getClientId(), identifier );

        this.log.info( "Returning " + monitoringReason.getName() +  "!" );

        return monitoringReason;
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see, two simple CDI converters, which are **almost** copies. The only difference is that list types are queried by name and monitoring reasons are queried by code. (see named queries, I checked that the correct ones are called by the services)

They are used from a JSF page like:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="list-type"
                 value="#{complianceCaseManager.selectedListType}"
                 converter="#{listTypeConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{listTypeManager.selectableListTypes}"
                   var="ltp"
                   itemValue="#{ltp}"
                   itemLabel="#{ltp.description}" />
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@form" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="monitoring-reason"
                 value="#{complianceCaseManager.selectedMonitoringReason}"
                 converter="#{monitoringReasonConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{monitoringReasonManager.selectableMonitoringReasons}"
                   var="mtr"
                   itemValue="#{mtr}"
                   itemLabel="#{mtr.name}" />
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@form" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

OK, same here, basically the same copied code. The only difference is that list types use `itemLabel="#{ltp.description}"` and monitoring reasons use `itemLabel="#{mtr.name}"` as UI labels.

What happens now is not what I had expected to happen:

The list type **and** monitoring reason converters both get the name as identifier from JSF. This isn't a problem for the list type converter as it uses a query with the name to find the respective entity. This happens when executing a selection change:

```
2012-12-18 22:51:23,923 [http-thread-pool-8181(5)] INFO  de.company.project.ListTypeConverter     - ListTypeConverter.getAsObject: RL
2012-12-18 22:51:23,927 [http-thread-pool-8181(5)] INFO  de.company.project.ListTypeConverter     - Returning RL!
```

However, when using the monitoring reason select, the following is logged:

```
2012-12-18 22:52:02,091 [http-thread-pool-8181(2)] INFO  de.company.project.MonitoringReasonConverter     - MonitoringReasonConverter.getAsObject: Fusion
2012-12-18 22:52:02,100 [http-thread-pool-8181(2)] ERROR de.company.project.MonitoringReasonService       - Monitoring reason not found for client ID = 1 with code Fusion
javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.throwNoResultException(EJBQueryImpl.java:1307)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:778)
    at de.company.project.MonitoringReasonService.findByClientIdAndCode(MonitoringReasonService.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7832.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7831.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
    at $Proxy2626.findByClientIdAndCode(Unknown Source)
    at de.company.project.__EJB31_Generated__MonitoringReasonService__Intf____Bean__.findByClientIdAndCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:110)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
    at de.company.project.MonitoringReasonService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.findByClientIdAndCode(MonitoringReasonService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
    at de.company.project.MonitoringReasonConverter.getAsObject(MonitoringReasonConverter.java:63)
    at de.company.project.MonitoringReasonConverter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getAsObject(MonitoringReasonConverter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:171)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectOneValue(MenuRenderer.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:318)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
    .
    .
    .
```

**Qs**:

1. Why is the name property taken to be used for **both** in the conversion process?
2. What determines that the name property *should* be used for the getAsObject method string value and not - as I had always assumed - the property passed into `itemLabel="..."`? How do you get control??
3. Where in the JSF spec is that information hidden? (if it's not PrimeFaces doing some overriding here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be the problem of Converter. I found a question similar to this, check this it may help.[Why selectOneMenu Send ItemLabel to the converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022965/why-selectonemenu-send-itemlabel-to-the-converter)

Comment: I'll give you the credit for pointing me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ultimately that my converter's `getAsString()` method defines the strings that `getAsObject` receives. I had always assumed that the value is determined by JSF, e.g. the `itemLabel="..."`, which isn't the case.

I kind of makes sense this way when thinking about it, but I'm rather shocked that I have missed this information for my 1.5+ years of reading and programming JSF...