# selectonemenu Validation Error: Value is not valid

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I'm using selectonemenu like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyBean.zajecie.przedmiot}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.przedmioty}" var="p"
        itemLabel="#{p.nazwa}" itemValue="#{p}" />
    <f:converter converterId="converter.PrzedmiotConverter" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

MyBean:

```
private Zajecie zajecie;//+set get
private List<Przedmiot> przedmioty;//+set get

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    przedmioty = przedmiotDao.findByLogin("login");
    zajecie = new Zajecie();
}
```

and the converter methods:

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    PrzedmiotDao przedmiotDao = DaoFactory.getInstance().getPrzedmiotDao();
    Przedmiot przedmiot = przedmiotDao.findById(Przedmiot.class, Integer.parseInt(value));
    return przedmiot;
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    Przedmiot przedmiot = (Przedmiot) value;
    String idAsString = String.valueOf(przedmiot.getPrzedmiotId());
    return idAsString;
}
```

The selectonemenu component is being populated as it's supposed to. When I submit, it shows `Validation Error: Value is not valid`. I know i need a proper `equals()` method for my entities so I've generated it with eclipse using only the id field. Then i had to change the test `getClass() != obj.getClass()` to `obj instanceof Przedmiot` because `obj.getClass()` returned something like this: `Przedmiot_$$_javassist_1`. I'm not sure if that is relevant because after  all `obj` proves to be `null`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

MyBean is ViewScoped.

Funny thing is that similar code using the same converter works in an other part of the application. The difference is that in the working part I'm just viewing the list of type `Przedmiot` and I'm obtaining it in another way.

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    student = studentDao.findByLogin(ra.getUser());
}

<h:selectOneMenu value="#{otherBean.przedmiot}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{otherBean.student.grupa.przedmiots}" var="p" 
        itemLabel="#{p.nazwa}" itemValue="#{p}" />
    <f:converter converterId="converter.PrzedmiotConverter" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 6):

Solved it. It was of course badly written `equals()` method.
First of all there was a mistake in my question. `obj` didn't resolve to null but `other.przedmiotId` did. Sorry for that. Look at the method generated by eclipse:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Przedmiot))//changed this from (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Przedmiot other = (Przedmiot) obj;
    if (przedmiotId == null) {
        if (other.przedmiotId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!przedmiotId.equals(other.przedmiotId))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

The issue is in `other.przedmiotId`. When obtaining the value with a getter `other.getPrzedmiotId()` it doesn't resolve to null anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In your converter: `Integer.parseInt(value)`, and in `<f:selectItems` you set `itemValue="#{p}"`, so each `#{p}` is instance of `Przedmiot` type.

See also:
[Why selectOneMenu Send ItemLabel to the converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022965/why-selectonemenu-send-itemlabel-to-the-converter)

Comment: Thats not working. I can't cast String to Przedmiot. Isn't the value supossed to represent a unique ID as explainded in the link you gave?

Comment: oh, so sorry, you get error when load page or submit to server ?

Comment: On submit. Validation fails.

Comment: when bugging, when error occur, line number(my English is not good, sorry) ?

Comment: When I click the submit button the validation error message is shown in h:messages component.