# Why selectCheckboxMenu passes values as its toString?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="producers"
                      value="#{products.producers}"
                      label="producers"
                      filter="true"
                      filterMatchMode="contains"
                      panelStyle="width: 400px"
                      style="width: 400px">
  <p:ajax update="productsTable"/>
  <f:selectItems value="#{producers.producers}" var="producer"
                 itemLabel="#{producer.name} (#{producer.uri})"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

My `Product` has following method.

```
public void setProducers(final List<Producer> producers) {
}
```

The list doesn't contains `Producer`s but the `String` value of `toString`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: See this unswer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022965/why-selectonemenu-send-itemlabel-to-the-converter)

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID Oh my God, Can I do that without converter?

Comment: What does God have to do with this?

Comment: You can't. You must use a converter.